# Eclipse mars code formatter for annotations containing other annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

Looking at moving from Luna to Mars (4.5.1) and the formatter adds a space in an annotation and I can't figure out which option to toggle to get it to be in the Luna format.

```
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "applicationId", column = @Column(name = "PROJ_ID", nullable = false, precision = 18) ),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "key", column = @Column(name = "KEY_VLU_KEY_STRG", nullable = false, length = 200) )})
    private ConfigKeyValuePairId id;
```

Mars formatter adds a space after the length / precision attribute.

Does anyone know which option would control this space?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Mars Java formatter has been completely rewritten from scratch and therefore behaves different than before in many more ways (and has a lot of open bugs), the easiest solution might be to actually [use the Luna formatter in Mars](http://eclipse-n-mati.blogspot.de/2015/06/eclipse-mars-how-to-switch-back-to.html) again.

Or if you just want the bugs of the new implementation fixed, you can even use the not yet released [formatter of Neon back in Mars](https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/use-the-latest-neon-version-of-the-formatter-with-mars.html).